# В справке по Markdown не переведено описание [tour]

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

[Справка по Markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting):

> [tour] – link to the Tour page. Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Также, спасибо [@VenZell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13336/venzell), он поправил строки. Добавил строки в движок. Они станут доступны после ближайшего разворачивания сборки.